# Two or more tables in the same line

Tags: tables

[image: I have done this in Microsoft Word, but I wish I could do it in LaTeX. Is it possible?]

Most like I've gotten so far is this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c |  c | c }
            \textbf{\textit{a}} &    & \\ \hline
               & \textbf{\textit{b}} & \\ \hline
               &    &  \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \\
            $ \dashrightarrow $\\
            \\
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ c |  c | c }
                \textbf{\textit{a}} &\textbf{\textit{ c}}  & \\ \hline
                \textbf{\textit{d}} & \textbf{\textit{b}} &\\ \hline
                   &    &  \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

with this result:

[image]

Comment: Obviously, the letters are misplaced, but that doesn't matter. The problem is, basically, the centering of the arrow and that it is thicker.

Comment: you have three minipage each .4\textwidth wide and with a word space between each of them so you are more than 1.2 times the available space. You don't need any of the minpages just have the tabluar, the arrow and the tabular separated by `\hfill`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  For future reference, it would be better to [edit] that first comment into the question.  Comments tend to get overlooked.  It would also be nice to have a paragraph explaining what you're trying to do.  Is the yellow highlighting part of your desired solution, or just happens to be in the picture that you posted?

Comment: Thanks a lot, David Carlisle. I just signed up on this site and I don't really know how this works, but I find it amazing to have gotten a response in such a short time.

Comment: Hello. Greetings to all. I'd like to be as respectful as possible of the forum rules, but I just came in for the first time and I still don't know how this works. So, I apologize for that and I thank you for your understanding of my first contact with this super professional forum.

Comment: As for the comment that I have made outside the question, it has been because I have not found a way to edit the question, to correct it.

What I wanted to achieve, and it has already been solved by https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/231952/ivan, was simply to place two tables in the same row, with an arrow between them. The content of the tables does not matter, and the yellow color, indeed, is only there because it was in the image that I captured. Could we achieve an arrow with thicker strokes, as shown in my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Just for fun, you can achieve that result with a simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{ c |  c | c }
    \textbf{\textit{a}} &    & \\ \hline
    & \textbf{\textit{b}} & \\ \hline
    &    &  \\
   \end{tabular}%
 \quad$ \dashrightarrow $\quad
    \begin{tabular}{ c |  c | c }
     \textbf{\textit{a}} &\textbf{\textit{ c}}  & \\ \hline
     \textbf{\textit{d}} & \textbf{\textit{b}} &\\ \hline
     &    &  \\
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan. You have helped me a lot; It's just what I needed. As you can see, I am starting with LaTeX ...

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarezLobo welcome to TeX.SE! Please accept it answer as the correct answer to take out your question from the queue of unanswered questions.

Comment: Sorry, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nox
It is not perfect, but it is good.